# detecting intersection between Circle and Line (not closed Path)

Tags: android, canvas, path, drawing

- I draw a line on the screen with an Android Path. -> drawPath. This path is NOT CLOSED !. So this is not a region.
- I have a circle on the screen -> drawCircle.

[image]

How can I detect if the circle is touching the line ?

There are answers to similar question, but with closed path. There I could simple intersect regions. But how can we do this in case of a NOT CLOSED Path ?

Any hints ?

Comment: no way in one shot - what you can use is `PathMeasure` and iterate points over the path

Comment: Ok I see. that I also was thinking. So I have to break up a bezier curve mathematically into to several points and check if one of theese points are touching the circle, right ? I still hope there is a simplier way, but thanks.

Comment: this is what `PathMeasure` is for - no need for any complex math

Answer (score 0):

Try this dumb solution and optimize it if you don't find any other solution:

- Create an empty bitmap
- Create a canvas using that bitmap.
- Draw circle in that canvas with red color.
- Traverse the pixels in the bitmap and store the indices of pixel which contain red pixel.
- Clear and draw that path in the canvas with black color.
- Traverse all the pixels in the bitmap and if the pixel is black and check if that index exists in the indices of the circle.
- If any index matches, then they overlap.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, but its not that what I am looking for. I understand, but this is really a hack. I look more for a mathematical or android api solution.

Comment: I know. That is why I told to use it only as a last resort.